# Return Count 0 in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have table called `Errorlogs` with a following data

```
+----+-------------+------------+
| ID | sps_Bereich | Date       |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 10 | helpeu1     | 2020-07-31 |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 11 | helpeu2     | 2020-07-31 |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 12 | helpeu3     | 2020-07-31 |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 13 | helpeu3     | 2020-07-31 |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 14 | helpeu4     | 2020-07-31 |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 15 | helpeu3     | 2020-07-30 |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 16 | helpeu4     | 2020-07-30 |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 17 | helpeu4     | 2020-07-30 |
+----+-------------+------------+
| 18 | helpeu4     | 2020-07-30 |
+----+-------------+------------+
```

I have another table called `Bereich`

```
+----+---------+
| ID | Name    |
+----+---------+
| 1  | helpeu1 |
+----+---------+
| 2  | helpeu2 |
+----+---------+
| 3  | helpeu3 |
+----+---------+
| 4  | helpeu4 |
+----+---------+
```

I would like to group by sps_bereich and Date and I am using the following query

```
select sps_bereich, [Date], count(*) as [Nr of errors] from [ErrorLogs] 
   where SPS_Bereich IN (
   select Name from [Bereich]
   )  
   group by SPS_Bereich, Date 
   order by date desc, SPS_Bereich asc
```

it gives me a following output.

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| sps_bereich | Date       | Nr of errors |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu1     | 2020-07-31 | 1            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu2     | 2020-07-31 | 1            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu3     | 2020-07-31 | 2            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu4     | 2020-07-31 | 1            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu3     | 2020-07-30 | 1            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu4     | 2020-07-30 | 3            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
```

what i would like to have is to include `sps_bereich` where there is no data.
in this case i would like to add `helpeu1,helpeu2` as `0` for a date `2020-07-30`

I would like to have following output.

```
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| sps_bereich | Date       | Nr of errors |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu1     | 2020-07-31 | 1            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu2     | 2020-07-31 | 1            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu3     | 2020-07-31 | 2            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu4     | 2020-07-31 | 1            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu1     | 2020-07-30 | 0            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu2     | 2020-07-30 | 0            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu3     | 2020-07-30 | 1            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
| helpeu4     | 2020-07-30 | 3            |
+-------------+------------+--------------+
```

I was thinking that adding a IN clause has to return me all values but this is not the case.

here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bd754/1).

Comment: you wanto to add a  date for each couple name\date or just for every name?

Comment: @Massimo for each Name when the date not exist in Errorlog than 0. so yes I would like to add a date for each Name.

Comment: I think there is confusion i edited my post.

Comment: no confusion, say there's a 5th name with no logs in any date. It should be listed for every date or for just one ?

Comment: @Massimo i have deleted that 5th name but if there is a 5th name than the output has to include helpeu5 --0 with a date 2020-07-31 and also for 2020-07-30. so for every date a name has to be there in final output as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left join -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0c7939d3a226a0368142a2737adf5d31)**

```
select A.Name, A.date,coalesce(B.cnt,0) as no_of_errors 
from
(select distinct date,name from Errorlogs cross apply Bereich)A
left join 
(select sps_Bereich, [Date],count(*) cnt
from Errorlogs group by sps_Bereich, [Date]
)B
on A.date=B.date and A.Name=B.sps_Bereich order by A.date desc, A.name asc
```

Comment: some how its give me a same result as my query.

Comment: @Tarun.P, I've edited my answer - you can check now

Comment: Great it works. can you give a short Explanation about this query. if possible. help others too.

Comment: @Tarun.P, you need to find the cross product of unique data and name of your main table since you would like to have an output which checks which product does not have any error every day. So first find the cross product of name and date based on two table using cross apply and then just use left join.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise writing the query as:

```
select b.name, d.date, count(el.id) as num_errors 
from Bereich b cross join
     (select distinct date from errorlogs) d left join
     errorlogs el
     on el.date = d.date and el.sps_Bereich = b.name 
group by b.name, d.date
order by d.date desc, b.name;
```

The idea is quite simple.  Use a `cross join` to generate the rows you want in the result set.  Then use `left join` to bring in the existing data.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=066b9018d7ece6bef35de56e7b678552) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
It builds a full grid of names and dates, then fills it with counts.

```
 select grid.name,grid.date,coalesce(cnt.cnt,0) from
  
    (select distinct e.date, d.name from errorlogs e, Bereich d) grid
    left outer join
    (
   select b.sps_Bereich, b.date, count(*) as cnt from [ErrorLogs] b
  
     group by b.sps_Bereich,b.date
    ) cnt  
    on grid.date=cnt.date and grid.name=cnt.sps_bereich
```

Comment: your answer is also great. it works. thanks for your help.